# Print graph in NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx

Is there a way to pretty print a graph in NetworkX? For example:

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> G = nx.Graph()
>>> G.add_edge('Alan', 'Bob')
>>> G.add_edge('Alan', 'Charles')
>>> G.add_edge('Alan', 'Xavier')
>>> G.add_edge('Charles', 'Xavier')
>>> G.add_edge('Joan', 'Xavier')
```

I would then like to see this graph as a json-like object, for example:

```
{
    'Alan': {
        'Bob': {},
        'Charles': {
            'Xavier': {}
        },
        'Xavier': {},
    },
    'Joan': {
        'Xavier': {}
    }
}
```

It doesn't have to be exactly like the above, but should give a good high-level data view of the graph (provided it's relatively small).

Comment: Can you provide and example of the printing you'd like to see?

Comment: @ScottBoston -- sure, I've updated the question with a better example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In newtorkx version 2.3, there is a method [`nx.to_dict_of_dicts`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/convert.html#dictionaries):

```
nx.to_dict_of_dicts(G)
```

Output:

```
{'Alan': {'Bob': {}, 'Charles': {}, 'Xavier': {}},
 'Bob': {'Alan': {}},
 'Charles': {'Alan': {}, 'Xavier': {}},
 'Xavier': {'Alan': {}, 'Charles': {}, 'Joan': {}},
 'Joan': {'Xavier': {}}}
```